# ECL connector(Widen DAM system) on Sites9.6 not working on new UI(Experience space), but working on classic UI

Tags: ecl, sites-9.6, experience-space

We have upgraded Sites from 9.1 to 9.6 and the Widen ECL add-on is working fine on classic UI. That means we are able to access the folders, images etc. But when we switch to new UI, the parent level folder(Widen folder) opens, but next-level folders wont open and throw some errors on the cme. Can somebody help to make it work on experience space as well?
I have attached the errors snapshot displayed on cme.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In general, you want to obtain more information (e.g. Stack Trace) from the ECL log file, but in this particular case, it seems the error message presented to the end user is already quite explicit: the ECL Provider (Widen ECL V2 Provider) returned `null` for a `GetItem` request for a given Widen ECL Folder.

ECL Providers (or Connectors) should never return `null` when ECL wants to get an item which they put in some list themselves. However, in releases before Sites 9.6 you may get quite far without noticing this bug in the ECL Provider.

Sites 9.6 does retrieve ECL Folders (in order to build full paths) from the ECL Providers and therefore, you will quickly get such error if the ECL Provider return `null` for its own ECL Folders.

See also [Custom ECL Provider GetItem method behaving differently in 9.6 environment](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/22114/custom-ecl-provider-getitem-method-behaving-differently-in-9-6-environment)

Comment: Just wondering to ask this - the same widen is working totally fine on 9.6 classic UI, but fails to load the folders when switched to experience space. Is this still expected?

Comment: Yes, that is expected. The new CM/ECL integration is mostly used for the Core Service REST integration (used by Experience Space).